# How can I get columns from Multi-Index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe called "keytable" which features a Multi-Index composed of 'Month', 'Day' and 'Hour'. I want to keep that multi-index while creating 3 new columns with the values of 'Month', 'Day' and 'Hour'. How can I do it?
Here's the dataframe:

```
keytable.head()
Out[59]: 
                 pp    pres  rad    rh  ...   ws  WeekDay   Power_kW  Power_kW18
Month Day Hour                          ...                                     
1     3   0     0.0  1027.6  4.1  78.9  ...  0.0        3  77.303046  117.774419
          1     0.0  1027.0  3.3  79.7  ...  0.0        3  72.319602  110.710928
          2     0.0  1027.0  3.3  81.8  ...  0.0        3  71.831852  106.067667
          3     0.0  1027.0  1.9  86.6  ...  0.0        3  69.555751  106.325955
          4     0.0  1027.0  3.8  92.2  ...  0.0        3  69.525780  102.855393

[5 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: but it has to have non-null values so it would look like: (1,3,0), (1,3,1), (1,3,2), (1,3,3), (1,3,4)....

Answer (score 1):

To make new columns called 'Month', 'day', 'year', just 
`new_table=key_table.reset_index()` will work. Having index duplicated as columns is a very poor practice, but if you really insist, then

```
newdf = new_table[['Year', 'Month', 'Year']].set_index(['Year', 'Month', 'Year']).
new_table.set_index(newdf.index, inplace=True)
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually did a reset_index() and un-dropped a datetime column so I can re-index it.

```
keytable=keytable.reset_index()
keytable['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(keytable['datahora'].str.replace('/','-'), errors='coerce')
keytable=keytable.set_index('datetime')
```